# How to lookup a value in a table with multiple criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I have a data sheet with multiple values in multiple columns.  I have a qty and a current price which when multiplied out gives me the current revenue (CurRev).

I want to use this lookup table to give me the new revenue (NewRev) from the new price but can't figure out how to do multiple ifs in a lookup.

[image]

What I want is to build a new column that checks the "Product", "Tier" and "Location/State" and gives me the new price from the lookup table (above) and then multiply that by the qty.

e.g. Data

```
> Product,  Tier,  Location, Qty, CurRev,   NewRev 
> Product1, Tier1, VIC,      2,   $1000.00, $6000 (2 x $3000) 
> Product2, Tier3, NSW,      1,   $100.00,  $200 (1 x $200)
> Product1, Tier3, SA,       5,   $250.00,  $750 (5 x $150)
> Product3, Tier1, ACT,      5,   $100.00,  $500(5 x $100)
> Product2, Tier3, QLD,      2,   $150.00,  $240 (2 x $240)
```

Worst case, if I just get the new rate I can create another column

Comment: Maybe I miss something, but where do you have the field `qty` on the source table? Where is `Location/State`?

Comment: Is the Product column in the lookup table filled with merged cells, or is that just border formatting?

Comment: Also, are the Tier labels shown here just as they are in the real data (i.e. are they named "Tier 1", "Tier 2", etc.)?  And are there exactly 3 Tiers for each Product?

Comment: @adam There is no qty in source table. Location is the header row.

Comment: @Excellll the product column in merged. AND Yes, tier labels are the same in the real data

Answer (score 0):

This solution makes two big assumptions about your data: 1) that each product has exactly three tiers; and 2) the product IDs in the lookup table are in merged cells.  Please let me know if this is not the case.

Here is a formula that will give you the `NewRev` value for a record in row 18.

```
=VLOOKUP(B18,INDIRECT("B"&MATCH(A18,$A$1:$A$10)&":J"&MATCH(A18,$A$1:$A$10)+2),MATCH(C18,$A$1:$J$1,0)-1,FALSE)*D18
```

This formula uses the `INDIRECT` function to define which part of the lookup table to use for your `VLOOKUP` based on the Product ID.  The column number for the `VLOOKUP` is attained by using a `MATCH` function to find the appropriate location.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be easier if column A showed the relevant product on every row. If you do that you can use this formula

`=INDEX(C$2:J$10,MATCH(1,INDEX((A$2:A$10=A18)*(B$2:B$10=B18),0),0),MATCH(C18,C$1:J$1,0))*D18`

....which follows a standard INDEX/MATCH/MATCH setup to get data from the intersection of a column and row header (complicated slightly here by having to match two criteria to get the row)